# lsp-mode tramp auto-completions

Tags: tramp, lsp-mode

Ive set up remote lsp-mode with tramp and pylsp server. While the server does start when I open a remote py file, many server features such as auto completions, code format, references dont work.

Here is my setup

```
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))

(use-package lsp-mode
    :hook (python-mode . lsp)
    :config
  (lsp-register-client
   (make-lsp-client :new-connection (lsp-tramp-connection "pylsp")
                    :major-modes '(python-mode)
                    :remote? t
                    :server-id 'pyls-remote)))

;; Set tramp remote path
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usrlocal/share/emacs/site-lisp/")
(require 'tramp)
(add-to-list 'Info-directory-list "/usr/local/share/info/")
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "~/envs/general/bin")
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path 'tramp-own-remote-path)

(use-package company
  :ensure t
  :diminish company-mode
  :hook (prog-mode . global-company-mode)
  :commands (company-mode company-indent-or-complete-common)
  :init)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh there's a typo

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usrlocal/share/emacs/site-lisp/")
```

should be
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/")

Cant believe I spent 40+ hours debugging this

Comment: we've all been there